# Passing TV value in a snippet (MODx Evo)

Tags: code-snippets, modx

Using MODx Evo 1.0.9. I am trying to use the following snippet to fetch youtube video title in a template:

```
<?php
$code = "<<<Youtube Video ID>>>";
$video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$code."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
$video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
$video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
$output = $video_str;
return $output;
?>
```

In the above code, I want to pass the youtube video ID from a TV in the `$code` variable. Using `[*youtubeID*]` does not work. What could be the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it works anything like Revo then the youtube id is available as the variable that you passed or as a scriptPrperty,

```
[[!MySnippetName? &youTubeId='456']]
```

then in your snippet:

```
<?php
$code = $youTubeId;
//or
$code = $scriptPropertes('youTubeId);//might have to check this one.
```